# Run multiple curl commands in parallel

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I have the following shell script. The issue is that I want to run the transactions parallel/concurrently without waiting for one request to finish to go to the next request. For example if I make 20 requests, I want them to be executed at the same time.

```
for ((request=1;request<=20;request++))
do
    for ((x=1;x<=20;x++))
    do
        time curl -X POST --header "http://localhost:5000/example"
    done
done
```

Any guide?

Comment: `curl -X POST ... &`?

Comment: If you are interested in load testing a particular URL and don't really insist on using `curl` maybe [hey](https://github.com/rakyll/hey) could be of interest.

Answer (score 97):

You can use `xargs`  with `-P` option to run any command in parallel:

```
seq 1 200 | xargs -n1 -P10  curl "http://localhost:5000/example"
```

This will run `curl` command 200 times with max 10 jobs in parallel.

Comment: For me it connects to 0.0.0.1, 0.0.0.2 and so on as well

Comment: This works for me but for some reason it doesn't exit out of the command when it's done,  and holds all the connections open (using `netstat -an | wc -l` to see open connections)  Any reason it does this? Is there way to get  it to exit at the end?

Comment: Yes it appends the number at end of the curl command. 

Simple fix is this
`seq 1 200 | xargs -Iname  -P10  curl "http://localhost:5000/example"`

Using  _I_  parameter we specify placeholder for argument, then we omit the argument in the command invocation

Answer (score 74):

Using `xargs -P` option, you can run any command in parallel:

```
xargs -I % -P 8 curl -X POST --header "http://localhost:5000/example" \
< <(printf '%s\n' {1..400})
```

This will run given `curl` command `400` times with max `8` jobs in parallel at a time.

Comment: `-P` runs given number of processes in parallel. `printf '%s\n' {1..400}` will print numbers from 1 to 400 and `curl` will run total 400 times with max 8 jobs in parallel.

Comment: Is it possible to print each output in a new line?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61249019/548225 you can run a bash script in `xargs` and can do anything there

Comment: The command is not working.
Try to copy it to the command line and execute.
It'll return
`bash: 0: ambiguous redirect`

Comment: Of course it works without any error on bash 4 or 5 versions. On older bash versions use: `printf '%s\n' {1..400} | xargs -I % -P 8 curl -I -X POST 'http://localhost:5000/example'`

Comment: I thought that reusing same TCP connection will be faster so `curl --parallel` should be faster than `xargs -P n`, But I found `xargs` is faster with `connection: close` for each request! May you describe Why please? Does `curl` see the parallelized jobs and reuse the same connection?

Answer (score 32):

**Update 2020:**

Curl can now fetch several websites in parallel:

```
curl --parallel --parallel-immediate --parallel-max 3 --config websites.txt
```

websites.txt file:

```
url = "website1.com"
url = "website2.com"
url = "website3.com"
```

Comment: How does a POST data work in this case?

Comment: @Josh You can send multiple POST requests like this:
`curl -i --parallel --parallel-immediate --parallel-max 3 -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"x":100}' --config websites.txt`

Comment: what about running x thousands request in parallel ...its curl capable of it ?

Comment: How do you send multiple data through same tcp connection and same url? I know about `--next` but I feel stupid repeating same long url, `-H` values with  diffrent `-d` values which leads to error `Arguments list too long`

Comment: You can add the `-L` and `--remote-name-all` options if you want curl to grab remote filenames after following locations.

Comment: Does not work for me. still runs it serially and waits for the POST to finish

Answer (score 13):

This is an addition to `@saeed's` answer.

I faced an issue where it made unnecessary requests to the following hosts

```
0.0.0.1, 0.0.0.2 .... 0.0.0.N
```

The reason was the command `xargs` was passing arguments to the curl command. In order to prevent the passing of arguments, we can specify which character to replace the argument by using the `-I` flag.

So we will use it as,

```sh
 ... xargs -I '$' command ...
```

Now, `xargs` will replace the argument wherever the `$` literal is found. And if it is not found the argument is not passed. So using this the final command will be.

```sh
seq 1 200 | xargs -I $ -n1 -P10  curl "http://localhost:5000/example"
```

**Note: If you are using `$` in your command try to replace it with some other character that is not being used.**

Answer (score 7):

Adding to `@saeed's` answer, I created a generic function that utilises function arguments to fire commands for a total of `N` times in `M` jobs at a parallel

```
function conc(){
    cmd=("${@:3}")
    seq 1 "$1" | xargs -n1 -P"$2" "${cmd[@]}"
}
```

```
$ conc N M cmd
$ conc 10 2 curl --location --request GET 'http://google.com/'
```

This will fire `10` curl commands at a max parallelism of two each.

Adding this function to the `bash_profile.rc` makes it easier. [Gist](https://gist.github.com/isopropylcyanide/10b9ba1548e5129b62b9e9395f3406c6)

Comment: Thanks, very convenient. One note: xargs will pass the index read from `seq` to the command. E.g. `conc 2 2 echo test` will print `test 1\ntest 2`. To avoid that, using `-I'$XARGI'` instead of `-n1` works (and you can use $XARGI in your command then if you need an index, or leave it out if you don't).

Answer (score 2):

Add “wait” at the end, and background them.

```
for ((request=1;request<=20;request++))
do
    for ((x=1;x<=20;x++))
    do
        time curl -X POST --header "http://localhost:5000/example" &
    done
done

wait
```

They will all output to the same stdout, but you can redirect the result of the time (and stdout and stderr) to a named file:

```
time curl -X POST --header "http://localhost:5000/example" > output.${x}.${request}.out 2>1 &
```

Comment: I tried this but it was giving me other issues. This is helpful though. Let do also the redirection of time to a file.

Comment: The "output to file" issue is tricky, and may have to be sent to a synchronized buffer (via GNU parallel), named pipes, or flock.

Answer (score 2):

Wanted to share my example how I utilised parallel xargs with curl.

The pros from using xargs that u can specify how many threads will be used to parallelise curl rather than using curl with "&" that will schedule all let's say 10000 curls simultaneously.

Hope it will be helpful to smdy:

```
#!/bin/sh

url=/any-url
currentDate=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
payload='{"field1":"value1", "field2":{},"timestamp":"'$currentDate'"}'
threadCount=10

cat $1 | \
xargs -P $threadCount -I {} curl -sw 'url= %{url_effective}, http_status_code = %{http_code},time_total = %{time_total} seconds \n' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST $url --max-time 60 -d $payload
```

.csv file has 1 value per row that will be inserted in json payload

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solution provided by [@isopropylcyanide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60789269/2035207) and the comment by [@Dario Seidl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/401712/dario-seidl), I find this to be the best response as it handles both curl and httpie.

```bash
# conc N M cmd - fire (N) commands at a max parallelism of (M) each
function conc(){
    cmd=("${@:3}")
    seq 1 "$1" | xargs -I'$XARGI' -P"$2" "${cmd[@]}"
}
```

For example:

```bash
conc 10 3 curl -L -X POST https://httpbin.org/post -H 'Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"url":"http://google.com/","foo":"bar"}'

conc 10 3 http --ignore-stdin -F -a user:pass httpbin.org/post url=http://google.com/ foo=bar
```