# How to use curl -Z (--parallel) effectively?

Tags: curl, command-line-interface

I need to download thousands of files with **curl**. I know how to parallelize with `xargs -Pn` (or `gnu parallel`) but I've just discovered curl itself can parallelize downloads with the argument `-Z|--parallel` introduced in **curl-7.66** ([see curl-goez-parallel](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2019/07/22/curl-goez-parallel/)) which might be cleaner or easier to share.
I need to use `-o|--output` option and `--create-dirs`. URLs need to be *percent-encoded*, the URL path becoming the folder path which also need to be escaped as path can contain single quotes, spaces, and usual suspects (hence `-O option` is not safe and `-OJ option` doesn't help).
If I understand well, curl command should be build like so:

```
curl -Z -o path/to/file1 http://site/path/to/file1 -o path/to/file2 http://site/path/to/file2 [-o path/to/file3 http://site/path/to/file3, etc.]
```

This works indeed, but what's the best way to deal with thousands URLS. Can a `config` file used with `-K config` be useful? what if the `-o path/to/file_x http://site/path/to/file_x` is the output of another program? I haven't found any way to record commands in a file, one command per line, say.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up asking on curl [user mailing list](https://curl.se/mail/archive-2022-03/0003.html).

The solution that worked for me was building a config (plain text) file built like so programmatically:

config.txt:

```
url=http://site/path/to/file1
output="./path/to/file1"
url=http://site/path/to/file2
output="./path/to/file2"
...
```

and use this curl command:

```
$ curl --parallel --parallel-immediate --parallel-max 60 --config config.txt
```

The command is a bit reacher than this and requires a recent curl version (7.81+)

```
$ curl --parallel --parallel-immediate --parallel-max 60 --config config.txt \
  --fail-with-body --retry 5 --create-dirs \
  --write-out "code %{response_code} url %{url} type %{content_type}\n"
```

For options like -K, --config  see https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html

HTH

Comment: Also refer to [run-multiple-curl-commands-in-parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46362284/run-multiple-curl-commands-in-parallel#answer-69644245)

Comment: for me it writes the full response body into each output file... any ideas how to make it write only response_code (using --write-out option) into each url result file?

Comment: Any way to add (different) request headers to each url in config file?

Comment: @Andrew I had not seen your comments. For your 1st comment, have you solved it with variables [https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/verbose/writeout](https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/verbose/writeout) : `curl -w "Type: %{content_type}\nCode: %{response_code} http://example.com`. Available variables are listed here [text-available-write-out-variables](https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/verbose/writeout#available-write-out-variables)

Comment: @Andrew. comment Any way to add (different) request headers to each url in config file ? I asked on curl-users mailing list ([response](https://curl.se/mail/archive-2023-07/0020.html)). So use next between urls  ex `header = "Accept: to the first URL"\n
url = http://first.example\n
next\n
header = "Accept: to the second URL"\n
url = http://second.example`