# How can I send multiple, seperately-defined POST request with curl simultaneously?

Tags: json, curl, post, simultaneous

I'm trying to test if my application can handle multiple simultaneous POST requests with custom headers.

I'm aware of this answer, [Run multiple curl commands in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46362284/run-multiple-curl-commands-in-parallel), but it doesn't quite meet my needs:

I want to send multiple, pre-defined post requests (with request bodies defined in .json files), and I want to send them all at once.

This is where I've got to. Am I missing something, or is this a reasonable way of executing this task?

```
curl --parallel --parallel-immediate --parallel-max 3 -u user:password -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @data1.json -H "customheader: customheader1" http://localhost:8000/rest/api/2/entity/ -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @data2.json -H "customheader: customheader2" http://localhost:8000/rest/api/2/entity/ -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @data3.json -H "customheader: customeheader1" http://localhost:8000/rest/api/2/entity/
```

Many thanks!